Pandas code using regex to convert all strings with single quote by another literal not working
I am trying to update a csv that has each line with multiple single quoted strings to one that replaces these strings to literal. but it puts all data in just first line in output. Can someone suggest what is the issue in the below code:
import pandas as pd
import re

df=pd.read_csv("t1.csv");
col1=df['col1']
col2=re.sub(r'\'([^\']*)\'','const',str(col1))
col3 = pd.Series(col2)

df['col1']=col3
df.to_csv('t_u.csv')
exit()

the file t1.csv has data like below:
col1
This one has 'many' 'such' 'quotes' in it.
Now it does not.
But 'this' 'one' does 'have' it 'too'.


The output generated has data like below ...which is wrong since it has only one line:
    col1
0   "0    This one has const const const in it.
1                              Now it does not.
2        But const const does const it const.
Name: col1, dtype: object"
1   
2   


What happened here is that all the 3 lines just got combined into a single line in the final output, whereas I am looking to have output of resulting csv to have same format - of 3 lines with the required changes.

Please provide the output of df.to_dict('tight') after the import (df=pd.read_csv("t1.csv")) for reproducibility

Hi Mozway,
Thanks for your inputs. I added that line and it ran without any issues and still the code gives the same output. that particular line did not generate any output when I ran the file.

You're doing str(col1), which converts the whole column into one string. Instead, see pandas applying regex to replace values. See also the docs: 10 minutes to pandas § String Methods

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips, like how to write a good title. ("not working" is not descriptive enough.)

@NiravShah this command is not supposed to solve your issue but returns a dictionary that you should add as [edit] to your question. If you run a script, use print(df.to_dict('tight')). Most likely, you need df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'\'([^\']*)\'', 'const', regex=True)

You most likely want to use str.replace with a regex:
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'\'([^\']*)\'', 'const', regex=True)

Output:
0    This one has const const const in it.
1                         Now it does not.
2     But const const does const it const.
Name: col1, dtype: object

